# Is Math.js capable of evaluating expressions in a topological order ?

Tags: javascript, mathjs

```
math.eval(["c = b" , "a = b + c"] , {"a" : 1, "b" : 2})
[2, 4]
```

Switching the order of the expressions,

```
math.eval(["a = b + c" , "c = b"] , {"a" : 1, "b" : 2})
Error: Undefined symbol c
```

Setting initial value for c to `NaN`

```
math.eval(["a = b + c" , "c = b"] , {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, c: NaN})
[NaN, 2]
```

Is math.js capable of evaluating expressions in a topological order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, math.js just evaluates the expressions sequentially.

Support for symbolic computations would be really nice though... See [these related discussions](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/search?q=symbolic&ref=cmdform&type=Issues) on github.

Comment: I've managed to achieve that with dirty checking (which is basically iterating through the expression list till you get no new results) but i was more interested if there is an underlying tree structure. Thanks.